# How to make a windows always on top like on-screen keyboard

Tags: c++, winforms, qt

Normally, when I bring a window up on top, it will affect other windows like taking their focus/cursor.

How to make a windows always on top, but cursor/control/focus remains on other windows like on-screen keyboard?

I am working on QT, but shed a light into visual C++ or windows api also help.

EDIT: Ok.. I got it worked now. Seems that I misunderstood how stay on top works

Comment: https://forum.qt.io/topic/1368/solved-how-to-make-always-top-window/5

Comment: I checked it but nothing mentioned stay on top without taking other's focus/cursor?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by stay on top without taking focus/cursor

Comment: Like on-screen keyboard. It is always on top but you can still do typing or working in other windows.

Comment: On screen keyboard is most likely directing all of its input to the "active" window, if there's a way to direct user input to another window that would be the way I'd go

Comment: ok.. I got it worked now. Seems that I misunderstood how stay on top works

Comment: Can your formulate an answer and accept it, so other people can benefit from it too?

Comment: @m7913d I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did in QT:

`window->setFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | window->flags());`